# Checking whether the clicked column is first in the row or not

Tags: jquery, html, css

wanted a Jquery code to check whether the clicked column is first in the Row or not.

A table is being used for selecting certain options. And onclick, the background of the clicked td is shown (A tick Mark) by assigning a CSS class using jquery and removing that class from all the sibling td elements (one selection per row).

The issue is that it should not do this on clicking the first column as it contains the Labels for  the option/question .

the current code is as follows:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("table tr td").click(function () {
        $(this).parent().find('td').each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass("CheckMark");
        });
        $(this).addClass("CheckMark");
    });
});
```

If the column is first, no action should be performed as it contains the Labels for option .

Hope to have explained the situation adequately :).

Kind regards,
A.Ali

Comment: you can add some class to first td in tr and check if clicked td have that class...

Comment: the below answer/reply seems to be performing the required task. :) . thank you for the time though ..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) to find out first column on click of `td`. If index() gives zero then it will be first column as `index()` gives *zero-based* index.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("table tr td").click(function () {

        if($(this).index() == 0) return;    

        $(this).parent().find('td').each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass("CheckMark");
        });
        $(this).addClass("CheckMark");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you .. The code seems to be working .. will accept as answer after 11 mins as Stack overflow is prompting that Answer can be marked after this time :) .. Thank you again.

Comment: Thumbs up for index()